# Skip the [skipping] tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[skipping](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/skipping) has no wiki definition and is used in various ways:

- failing to process fragments of audio or video
- intentionally ignoring items when processing a list like a playlist
- searching for the next element that meets some criteria, like a bad block on a hard disk, and moving directly to it
- bypassing a process like triggering a log-in screen
- moving the cursor in fixed increments like the start of each word

They are similar in the most general sense of leaving something out, but not in a way that makes the tag useful without other tags for context.

Recommendation: eliminate [skipping](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/skipping) as a stand-alone tag.  Create something like [audio-skipping](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/audio-skipping) and [video-skipping](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/video-skipping) that would apply to missing fragments and possibly ignoring items in a playlist.  Some uses would fit the existing [bypass](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bypass) or [search](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/search) tags.  Some of the tag uses were probably a poor choice of tag.